# make div height automatically adjust to viewport using css

Tags: css

I want to show data in table which should scroll when data in `tbody` is exceeding `viewport` height.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/91zxh69r/

I am able to make it scroll using

```
{
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

But the problem here is its height is getting fixed because of `max-height: 200px`.

How can I make `tbody` height adjustable according to `viewport` using css ?
Can anybody please help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the table with div and stretch the wrapping div over the height:

HTML

```
<div class="tableWrapper">
    <table>
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tableWrapper { height: 100%; overflow: auto; }
```

Comment: Do I need to wrap the table which has tbody ?

Comment: @Pratik: Maybe not, but I would personally let the table to be rendered as normal table without adjusting it that much and without trying to force the scrollbar appear directly within the `<table>` element when not necessary.

Comment: Here the reason I chose to use two tables is because I want to fix the headers and keep the rows scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use @media where you set max-height depending on which screen size your program is using.

```
@media (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px) {
@viewport {
max-height: 400px;
}
}
```